# Associate a rails model with a mysql database table of a different name

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

So I am working on a project for a client that wants to use an old mysql database for a new site.

I cannot change the names  of the tables in the database because another app uses the same database.  I am using Rails to code the new site.

The current name of the tables in the database don't match Rails naming conventions. Is there a way to associate a model "user.rb" with the table name "tbl_user"?

(Also, I tried creating a .rb file named "tbl_user" but the table name would need to be "tbl_users").

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as following:

In your model file `user.rb`, you put this line:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name 'tbl_user'
end
```

And your model `User` will map to your table `tbl_user`

Comment: Thank you for the response!  After I changed my user.rb file like you said, I went to the consle and tried User.new and got the following error (any ideas why?): User.new
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:134:in `table_name'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample-app/app/models/user.rb:2:in `<class:User>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample-app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: ah, ha, I checked the documentation and the code should read self.table_name = 'tbl_user'. Thank you for putting me on the right track!

Comment: @sb4f1 if my answer help you, you can mark my answer as useful answer.